# Geting error firebase rules. When I can it to first then My Setup profile activity is showing whenever i change ".write":true it didn't show

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I  have a problem Please help me.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

I have an activity for Setup Profile. When I can change rules to above then setup activity didn't show to me but when i change `".write":false` then it show setup activity but i can't upload anything to Firebase.
here above is the database  you ask to add but by this setup activity didn't show but if i can change this to

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

then setup activity show up but i can upload anything to firebase database.
What i can do in this situation? Reply Please

Comment: Security rules don't do anything without code that is checked against them. Please edit your question to include the minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Also try to provide a more concise title for the question. You can add some of the details in the body.

Comment: I tell you the story. I'm adding validation after login, user go to the setup activity where he can add his profile and other info.

Answer (score 0):

this is not the answer?

I tell you the story. I'm adding validation after login, user go to the setup activity where he can add his profile and other info. here is below the checking user existence
'@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();

```
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (currentUser == null) {
        SendUserToLoginActivity();
    } else {
        CheckUserExistence();
    }
}

private void CheckUserExistence() {
    final String current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    UsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(current_user_id)) {
                SendUserToSetupActivity();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}'
```

everything works fine. but the main problem is when i change the Firebase Database Rules.
when I add `{ "rules": { ".read": true, ".write": false } }` 
then it show the Setup Activity. But I can't upload anything to firebase.
And If I can change the rules to `{ "rules": { ".read": true, ".write": true } }` 
then it didn't show setup activity.
Here is my problem please Let me know the solution.